# Comparing neighboring integer does not work in Permute Array of Integers Duplicates Allowed

Tags: java, combinations, permutation

Given an array of numbers with possible duplicates, return all of its permutations in any order.

It works when I use a HashSet to skip duplicates.

```
    package test;

import java.util.*; 

public class test {
      static ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> get_permutations(ArrayList<Integer> arr) {
            ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> res=new ArrayList<>();
            //Collections.sort(arr);
            helper(arr, 0, res);
            return res;
        }
        
        static void helper(ArrayList<Integer> arr, int pos, ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> res){
            int n=arr.size();
            if(pos>=n){
                res.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(arr));
                return;
            }
            
            Set<Integer> set=new HashSet<>();
            for(int i=pos; i<n; i++){
                //if(i>pos&&arr.get(i).equals(arr.get(i-1)))  
                if(!set.add(arr.get(i)))
                    continue;
                
                Collections.swap(arr, pos, i);
                helper(arr, pos+1, res);
                Collections.swap(arr, pos, i);
            }
        }
    // Driver code
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> arr= new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(3,3,8,8,9,9,9));
        for(var v:get_permutations(arr)){
            System.out.println(v);
        }
    }
}
```

However, if I sorted the array and skipped the duplicates by comparing neighboring integer, it does not work for some test cases such as [3,3,8,8,9,9,9].

```
    import java.util.*; 
    
    public class test {
          static ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> get_permutations(ArrayList<Integer> arr) {
                ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> res=new ArrayList<>();
                Collections.sort(arr);
                helper(arr, 0, res);
                return res;
            }
            
        static void helper(ArrayList<Integer> arr, int pos, ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> res){
            int n=arr.size();
            if(pos>=n){
                res.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(arr));
                return;
            }
            
            //Set<Integer> set=new HashSet<>();
            for(int i=pos; i<n; i++){
                if(i>pos&&arr.get(i).equals(arr.get(i-1)))  
                //if(!set.add(arr.get(i)))
                    continue;
                
                Collections.swap(arr, pos, i);
                helper(arr, pos+1, res);
                Collections.swap(arr, pos, i);
            }
        }
    // Driver code
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> arr= new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(3,3,8,8,9,9,9));
        for(var v:get_permutations(arr)){
            System.out.println(v);
        }
    }
}
```

This is opposite to [subset solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74083916/using-hashset-to-filter-duplicates-does-not-work-in-subsets-with-duplicate-probl).

The outputs highlighted in red part are the problem.

[image]

What did I miss here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Coach in Interview Kickstart helped me found out the problem in my code.  His/Her finding is
"In the if condition of for loop, You have written if(i>pos&&arr.get(i).equals(arr.get(i-1))) but it should be if (i != pos && (arr.get(i) == arr.get(pos) || (i > 0 && arr.get(i) == arr.get(i-1)))) to handle the duplicate elements correctly."

I have converted the fix to what I can understand better -

if (i > pos && (arr.get(i) == arr.get(pos) || arr.get(i) == arr.get(i-1)))

Earlier I missed the case arr.get(i) == arr.get(pos).

The correct solution is

```
    import java.util.*; 
    
    public class test {
          static ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> get_permutations(ArrayList<Integer> arr) {
                ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> res=new ArrayList<>();
                Collections.sort(arr);
                helper(arr, 0, res);
                return res;
            }
            
        static void helper(ArrayList<Integer> arr, int pos, ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> res){
            int n=arr.size();
            if(pos>=n){
                res.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(arr));
                return;
            }
            
            for(int i=pos; i<n; i++){
                if (i > pos && (arr.get(i) == arr.get(pos) || arr.get(i) == arr.get(i-1)))
                    continue;
                
                Collections.swap(arr, pos, i);
                helper(arr, pos+1, res);
                Collections.swap(arr, pos, i);
            }
        }
    // Driver code
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> arr= new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(3,3,8,8,9,9,9));
        for(var v:get_permutations(arr)){
            System.out.println(v);
        }
    }
}
```