# Using HashSet to filter duplicates does not work in subsets with duplicate problem

Tags: java, subset

The problem is "Given a list of numbers that may contain duplicates, return all possible subsets (the power set).

The solution set must not contain duplicate subsets. Return the solution in any order."

I have some simple code to use seemly similar ways to solve this problem.  Howerver, Hashset approach does not work for some test cases such as [10, 10, 1, 2, 2, 2, 10].  But sort and neighbor integer comparison approach work.

It is just different from [the permutation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74083841/permute-array-of-integers-duplicates-allowed).

This code works:

```
import java.util.*; 

public class test {
    static ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> subsets_with_duplicate(ArrayList<Integer> numbers) {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> res=new ArrayList<>();
        Collections.sort(numbers);
        helper(res, new ArrayList<>(), numbers, 0);
        return res;
    }

    static void helper(ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> res, ArrayList<Integer> slate, ArrayList<Integer> numbers, int pos){
        int n=numbers.size();

        res.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(slate));
        //Set<Integer> set=new HashSet<>();
        for(int i=pos; i<n; i++){
            //if(!set.add(numbers.get(i)))
            if(i!=pos&&numbers.get(i).equals(numbers.get(i-1)))
                continue;
            slate.add(numbers.get(i));
            helper(res, slate, numbers, i+1);
            slate.remove(slate.size()-1);
        }
    }
    // Driver code
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> arr= new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(10, 10, 1, 2, 2, 2, 10));
        for(var v:subsets_with_duplicate(arr)){
            System.out.println(v);
        }
    }
}
```

This code does not work -

```
import java.util.*; 

public class test {
    static ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> subsets_with_duplicate(ArrayList<Integer> numbers) {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> res=new ArrayList<>();
        //Collections.sort(numbers);
        helper(res, new ArrayList<>(), numbers, 0);
        return res;
    }

    static void helper(ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> res, ArrayList<Integer> slate, ArrayList<Integer> numbers, int pos){
        int n=numbers.size();

        res.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(slate));
        Set<Integer> set=new HashSet<>();
        for(int i=pos; i<n; i++){
            if(!set.add(numbers.get(i)))
            //if(i!=pos&&numbers.get(i).equals(numbers.get(i-1)))
                continue;
            slate.add(numbers.get(i));
            helper(res, slate, numbers, i+1);
            slate.remove(slate.size()-1);
        }
    }
    // Driver code
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> arr= new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(10, 10, 1, 2, 2, 2, 10));
        for(var v:subsets_with_duplicate(arr)){
            System.out.println(v);
        }
    }
}
```

Why?

The partial output difference between these two solutions are highlighted in red.

[image]

Comment: Are you aware that `Set`s like `HashSet` simply don't allow duplicate elements?  If you add 10 and 10 to one, you get a set with 10 in it?

Comment: @LouisWasserman here is the power set.  The integer elements may have the same value, but they are not the same.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I guess you remind me of why using hashset does not work, since hashset filters elements with the same values.  But I am still confused why the hashset solution has more outputs.

Comment: Each call to `helper` creates a new set, so you only have a unique result within a single `helper` invocation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `Collections.sort(numbers);` in your last program. If you uncomment then it will show the same result as earlier. Because without the HashSet code you are sorting data but not in the second program.

```
static ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> subsets_with_duplicate(ArrayList<Integer> numbers) {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> res = new ArrayList<>();
    Collections.sort(numbers);
    helper(res, new ArrayList<>(), numbers, 0);
    return res;
}

static void helper(ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> res, ArrayList<Integer> slate, ArrayList<Integer> numbers,
        int pos) {
    int n = numbers.size();

    res.add(new ArrayList<>(slate));
    Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
    for (int i = pos; i < n; i++) {
        if (!set.add(numbers.get(i))) {
            // if ((i != pos) && numbers.get(i).equals(numbers.get(i - 1))) {
            continue;
        }
        slate.add(numbers.get(i));
        helper(res, slate, numbers, i + 1);
        slate.remove(slate.size() - 1);
    }
}

// Driver code
public static void main(String args[]) {
    ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(10, 10, 1, 2, 2, 2, 10));
    for (var v : subsets_with_duplicate(arr)) {
        System.out.println(v);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.  However, when we use HashSet, Collections.sort(numbers) is not needed.  Collections.sort(numbers) is for the neighboring elements comparison only.

Comment: you are correct.  We need to add Collections.sort(numbers) to make these two solutions output the same result.  The problem does not say that the result needs to be sorted.  But they really expect that.